# How to mask sections of a PBR Node set up

Tags: texturing, node-editor

I have set up a PRB node with grunge scratches on a glass material. I would like to be able to control from the middle of the grunge texture, to the border of the glass how much of the grunge texture expands inner and towards towards outer.

this is an example I did in Photoshop, I can use the slider to reveal and hide the masking section.

[image]
[image]